# Increase/ decrease value of input field with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've added some functionality to my shopping cart to change the quantity of the products. So there is a plus and a minus button next the the quantity input field.
This is the code:

```
 <button type="submit" id="qtyMinus" class="qtyMinus" title="<?php echo $this->__('Update') ?>"  data-qty="-1"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
    <input name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]" value="<?php echo $this->getQty() ?>" size="4" id="qtyField" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" maxlength="12" type="text"/>


<button type="submit" id="qtyPlus" title="<?php echo $this->__('Update') ?>"  class="qtyPlus" data-qty="1"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                        <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Update') ?>" class="button btn-update-qty btn-alt btn-new"><span><span class="updateNew"><?php echo $this->__('Update') ?></span></span></button>
```

And the jquery:

```
 $j("#qtyPlus").click(function(){
    var $n = $j("#qtyField");
    $n.val( Number($n.val())+1 ); 
});

 $j("#qtyMinus").click(function(){
    var $n = $j("#qtyField");
    $n.val( Number($n.val())-1 ); 
});
```

Now, this works however if more than one different product is added the buttons of the second product won't work- I assume because they've got the same id. Can anybody think of a better way of doing this or a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not have same id more that once in a document. Change Ids to classes and put each item in a parent wrapper:

```
<div class="product"> 
<button type="submit" id="qtyMinus" class="qtyMinus" title="<?php echo $this->__('Update') ?>"  data-qty="-1"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
    <input name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]" value="<?php echo $this->getQty() ?>" size="4" id="qtyField" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" maxlength="12" type="text"/>


<button type="submit" class="qtyPlus" title="<?php echo $this->__('Update') ?>"  class="qtyPlus" data-qty="1"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                        <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Update') ?>" class="button btn-update-qty btn-alt btn-new"><span><span class="updateNew"><?php echo $this->__('Update') ?></span></span></button>
</div>
```

Now you can simply do this:

```
 $j(".qtyPlus").click(function(){
    var n=$(this).closest('.product').find('.qtyField');
    n.val( Number(n.val())+1 ); 
});
```

Comment: @MariaL glad that it helped

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have more then one element with ID qtyPlus. You ID need to be unique, like qtyPlus_1 for first item an qtyPlus_2 for second and so on.

And so to increment first item it will be:

```
 $j("#qtyPlus_1").click(function(){
    var $n = $j("#qtyField");
    $n.val( Number($n.val())+1 ); 
});
```

Comment: So if there is 10 products you add this code 10 times? Not very efficient, maybe us css-classes and I'll upvote :)

Comment: @Esko I think my my answer would be right, He wouldn't have to add the code 10 times;;

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
     $j(".qtyPlus").click(function(){
    var $n = $(this).parent().find("#qtyField");
    $n.val( Number($n.val())+1 ); 
});

 $j(".qtyMinus").click(function(){
    var $n = $(this).parent().find("#qtyField");
    $n.val( Number($n.val())-1 ); 
});
```

But for this to work, Every product should be inside unqiue div. For example: our html should be something like this:

```
<div>     
<button type="submit" id="qtyMinus" class="qtyMinus" title="<?php echo $this->__('Update') ?>"  data-qty="-1"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
        <input name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]" value="<?php echo $this->getQty() ?>" size="4" id="qtyField" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" maxlength="12" type="text"/>


    <button type="submit" id="qtyPlus" title="<?php echo $this->__('Update') ?>"  class="qtyPlus" data-qty="1"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                            <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Update') ?>" class="button btn-update-qty btn-alt btn-new"><span><span class="updateNew"><?php echo $this->__('Update') ?></span></span></button>
    </div>
    <div>
     <button type="submit" id="qtyMinus" class="qtyMinus" title="<?php echo $this->__('Update') ?>"  data-qty="-1"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
        <input name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]" value="<?php echo $this->getQty() ?>" size="4" id="qtyField" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" maxlength="12" type="text"/>


    <button type="submit" id="qtyPlus" title="<?php echo $this->__('Update') ?>"  class="qtyPlus" data-qty="1"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                            <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Update') ?>" class="button btn-update-qty btn-alt btn-new"><span><span class="updateNew"><?php echo $this->__('Update') ?></span></span></button>
     </div>
```

. Hope this helps. Here is the fiddle :-https://jsfiddle.net/1bg1pnyf/4/

Comment: How does this solve the problem: _"the buttons of the second product won't work"_ ?

Comment: @Andreas. I thought it was class.. Thanks for pointing it out... I will correct this answer

Comment: This still won't work correctly because of `#qtyField`

Comment: You have to change the `id=qtyField` part in the `<input />` also to be a class instead and then adjust the selector used to find the input. Or remove the id completely and use `.find("input")` instead of `.find("#qtyField")`

Comment: @Andreas but why can't i use class.... That is working... Also .find("input") would also work..

Comment: You're not using a class: `$(this).parent().find("#qtyField");`

Comment: @Andreas You forgot something about jquery. In this $(this).parent().find("#qtyField"); this command is telling the jquery to select the parent node of the clicked element and then find a element named qtyField in it, So if we go by this concept, then the #qtyField will not create any issues.... Because id is unqiue in reference to its parent..... I think my conecept is right or else the fiddle wouldn't have worked. Please have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

You can use class name instead of id. And data-attribute to get the other value related to current product.

```
$j(".qtyPlus").on('click', function(){
    var $n = $(this);
    $n.val( Number($n.data('qty'))+1 ); 
});
```